# JQuery display concatenated list of text from visible HTML table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table.  In the first `td` in each row, there is a farmer's name (e.g., "farmer1", "farmer2", etc.).  So, each row represents information on a different farmer.  Suppose that for some valid reason some of the rows are hidden.  At any given time, I want to be able to show a list of the farmers that are visible in the table.

For example, if the state of my table looks like this

```
Farmer #  | apple | orange | pear
farmer2   |   0   |   1    |  1 
farmer3   |   0   |   1    |  0
farmer4   |   0   |   1    |  0
```

I want to have a link that, when clicked, will toggle the visibility of the following string (text) on an area of the page:

```
farmer2 farmer3 farmer4
```

Here is an almost fully functional solution: [jsfiddle.net/8aszmfkq/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8aszmfkq/2/)

The part I can't figure out is how to extract the text in the first `td` of each visible row, concatenate the extracted text, and write the concatenated text to a div.  (If you remove the JS call to `updateFarmerList()`, you can see that the toggle works... the problem is really extracting and concatenating.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: this.text is not a function

Please correct  `$(this.text())` to  `$(this).text()`

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8aszmfkq/3/

Comment: I guess I was relying too heavily upon the "JSHint" button on jsfiddle.

Comment: I will accept it as soon as it lets me :)  Quick question: how do you debug/validate JS? (I'm very new to JS/JQuery.)

Comment: just put F12 key on your keyboard...it will open the JavaScript console and will show you the syntax errors. Though their are many development intellisense tools available..but i believe in simplicity. :)

Comment: Thanks. I agree on simplicity. Especially since I'm not a web developer, but one who is learning a little.

Comment: Learning is never ending...I am also preparing a HTML5 Canvas based application without a server interaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70151/discussion-between-vijay-and-synaptik).